# Scrolling div contents with css overflow

Tags: html, css

I've just started learning html and css and I'm trying to create a simple static website. My problem is that I'm trying to make a div container(`option2`) scroll with css `overflow:auto`.

The thing is that there are inner divs that are misplaced, overlapping, etc. when `overflow:auto` is in effect. `#box2` is a inner div of `#option2`. `#box2text` is inner div of `#box2` div.

### HTML

```
<div id="option2">
    <div id="box2">
        <img class="pic1" src="img/button top/user1.png"></img>
        <div id="box2text">Text for updates, news, events, ect.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <img class="pic1" src="img/button top/user1.png"></img>
        <div id="box2text">Text for updates, news, events, ect.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <img class="pic1" src="img/button top/user1.png"></img>
        <div id="box2text">Text for updates, news, events, ect.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <img class="pic1" src="img/button top/user1.png"></img>
        <div id="box2text">Text for updates, news, events, ect.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#option2 {
    height:90%;
    width:35%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:2%;
    min-height:90%;
    position:apsolute;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:auto;
    display:block;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid white;
}
#box2 {
    height:25%;
    width:90%;
    float:center;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    bottom:0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid white;
}
img.pic1 {
    float:left;
    height:80px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid white;
}
#box2text {
    float:right;
    height:80%;
    width:65%;
    margin-right:1%;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:grey;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border:solid white;
}
```

Comment: `position:apsolute;`? I guess you meant `position:absolute;`. Also `float` cannot be applied on absolutely positioned objects, they are moved from their context. `center` is not a valid `float` value. IDs should to be unique, use classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only things I can see that's a problem is that in the css for #option2, you have `absolute` spelled incorrectly and you are trying to use a float value of `center`.  To center an element horizontally, use

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto
```

Also, an id should only be used once.  While it usually doesn't affect how the browser renders the HTML, it is incorrect according to HTML standards.  Having multiple elements with the same id can cause confusion in the browser, especially if you want to use JavaScript to manipulate those elements.

See this jsfiddle with `absolute` corrected:  http://jsfiddle.net/qpkJV/1/